# Draw svg shape from an image in python

Tags: python, svg, graphics, computer-vision

I want to create an SVG shape from a PNG in python. Basically I want create [this](https://createmath.online/1643694118662.svg) type of SVG. I've searched a lot in stack overflow and in the internet and got [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/creating-svg-image-using-pycairo/) tutorial which uses pycario to draw a svg. It works fine for me, but the problem is these SVG paths are hard-coded here.I want to automatically generate the path from an image like [image: this].

So that pycario can generate a svg shape from it like [this](https://createmath.online/1643694118662.svg)

If anyone can answer this, it would be very helpful to me. Thanks in advance. Please let me know if any further clarification needed.

Comment: Can you clarify what input you want to give your program in order to create this SVG output? Do you want to input coordinates of the points, or values of the lengths, or do you want it to be able to detect these from a photograph like you've added to the question?

Comment: I want to input a photograph,like I've added in the question.

Comment: This is possible but extremely difficult. You'll need to do some object detection in order to determine lines and circles etc. I think this is too broad a question for SO I'm afraid.

Comment: Can you please briefly discuss this. Or is there any another way to draw svg from an image.

Comment: There's too much complexity to this probelm to discuss this briefly, but there is lots of material online for circle and line detection in python. I'd go through the opencv tutorials and look at line and circle detection. Creating the SVG will come much later once you've been able to detect each component in your image, but there are python libraries like drawSvg that will help at this later stage.

Comment: Try potrace perhaps. It's not python but you could call it from python I suppose. The potrace homepage lists some alternatives: http://potrace.sourceforge.net/